# Can I create a knowledge graph in Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

I know that knowledge graphs are represented in RDF, but I am wondering whether Memgraph as a graph database can store this kind of data?

Answer (score 0):

While Memgraph is not an RDF store, it is capable of handling this kind of data with the labeled property graph model (LPG). LPG is represented by a set of nodes, relationships, properties (key-value attributes) and labels. RDF statements can be directly treated as nodes, relationships and properties of the graph, which are explored using the Cypher query language. Therefore, both RDF and LPG allow the creation of a knowledge graph.